# How to initialize a c++11 native pointer and array in a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example

```
class A
{
 int *p{};   // is this fine without giving the null pointer value 0?
 int p[3]{}; // is this fine without double braces {{ }}? std::array need.
};
```

My testing shows they pass intel c++ compiler. But not sure if they are standardly right or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and yes.

It would be better explicitly initialize with nullptr, like `int *p = nullptr;`.

`int p[3]{}` will initialize every p with int{}.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, data members of any type, including aggregate (e.g., an array type), can be initialized in different ways using a uniform [list-init syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). By putting an empty pair of braces as the initializer, you are performing [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). But you can perform other kinds of initializations as well. Also note that, since C++14, nested braces in [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) can be elided in all cases. So, `std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};` is OK since C++14.